# FormField for Varchar to a <select> + other as free text

Tags: php, silverstripe

For a standard `Varchar` (or `Text`) db field I'd like to replace this with a set of fixed options - but still allow "other" to be selected and for the user to enter a string of their choice.

```
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {
    static $db = array(
        'MyVarchar'      => "Varchar",
    );  

    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->replaceField(
             'MyVarchar',
              SomeField(
                   'MyVarchar',
                   'Choose an option or enter text',
                   array(1 => 'Option1',2 => 'Option2')
             )
        );

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

So I'm looking for something to use as `SomeField` and the user will see a drop down with the values Option1, Option2 and Other.  If Option1 or 2 is selected then this is saved into MyVarchar.  If Other is selected then it would allow specifying the text directly of MyVarchar as normal.

I'm hopeful there is, as in the case of other answers I've received, a pre-existing module for this.

Comment: It is hard to tell just what you are asking here. What is happening? What is your expected outcome? Do you want us to write code for you?

Comment: There is no such field as far as I know, but behaviour you have described is quite common. Split the form with DropdownField('MyVarchar', $title, $options) and TextField('MyVarcharOther', $title, $existingValueIfCustom). Handle these fields in onBeforeWrite() to choose actual value.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I'm asking for a text field to be populated via a drop down or "other" that would populate as text. If you want to write code as a solution that is fine - I could write it for each case or a FormField but I'd prefer not to reinvent the wheel and I often find cases for open source CMS like Silverstripe have modules - I'm hoping it will be one of those...

Comment: @GregSmirnov - yep that is exmple what wmk has recommend (directly to me) however I have many of these fields and don't like to repeat myself and would prefer to use a module if there is one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And...
I've found basically what I was after...

https://github.com/Leapfrognz/alternative-field

Thank you Leapfrognz!

Comment: Great news - it's got a bug in it!  https://github.com/Leapfrognz/alternative-field/issues/5